# Loading C# form into ActiveX control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, activex

Is it possible loading C# form (or C# application) into ActiveX control? I know how to load ActiveX control to C# form....

Answer (score 0):

You can call a .Net form in VB6 (with Interop Forms Toolkit 2.0), and you can use VB6 to create an ActiveX so my guess is that it is possible.

I have also heard of ppl used forms created from .net-dlls and den using setparent-api and got it to act as a child to vb6-form.

All in all, yes it seems possible to load an C#-form in an activeX control.

**Interop Forms Toolkit 2.0: display .NET Winforms in VB6 Applications**
http://hubpages.com/hub/Interop_Forms_Toolkit_20

And someone using SetParent, not a solution but from this its easy to google away to other solutions.
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/NETFrameworkinterop/Oct2005/post24062147.asp